# Different post into a single page

Tags: customization, single

i am having a little trouble here.
Well what i am exactly trying to do is post posts into different divs in my wordpress template in a single page.
[image]

How am it to achieve different posts in different divs.

Comment: can you explain more? `single.php` is usually used to display a single post. What are the other different posts?

Answer (score -1):

Add the below code in your single.php file

```
<div class="post-contents">
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1,'orderby'=> 'date','order'=> 'DESC','post_type' => 'post','post_status'=> 'publish');
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div class="post-single">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <p><?php echo $post->post_content; ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
</div>
```